# Custom actions and objects for sharing radio station and songs via Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an online radio streaming app. I want to allow users to share to facebook the radio station or song they are listening to.

I see there is an action "listen", nice! However, I also see I can't use it. [Music actions have been deprecated and are no longer available.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions) Ok, so then I looked at what action I could use? None seemed to fit so I created my own "share" action. That seems to fit perfect. My concer "share" seems generic and will that get approved?

Ok, so action solved? Now I need the object for radio station and song. I see that [music.song](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/music.song/) and [music.radio_station](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/music.radio_station/) is available for use! Awesome, oh wait hidden somewhere in Facebook says I can't use it? Only [whitelabel partners](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music)? What the heck?!!!

Fine, I can I guess create my own song and radio station objects? Again, my concern would these objects get approved? What would be the difference between my custom object and those nice unusable music objects?

Comment: Only way to find out for sure if you’ll get those approved, is to implement and submit them for review.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose... I just didn't want to spend dev time on something that might not happen. They require actual app to look at and verify how it works.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I suppose you could always fall back to letting your user make normal posts, and share a link that contains a playable version of your song (flash and/or mp4.)